# is this route possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

hi im new in ruby on rails development and currently im working in a reservation system i made a semi static page with a controller inside it has a functionroom action 
my functionroom action is

```
 def functionroom
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
    @function_room = FunctionRoom.all 
  end
```

but when i try to route to functionroom coming from the reservation module with this route
`<%= link_to "add functionrooms", reservation_pages_functionroom_path(@reservation) %>`

it gives me a `uninitialized constant Reservations` error
im just wondering if im working with my routes right dealing with the pages/functionroom static page.

```
resources :reservations do
   resources :reservation_function_rooms
   resources :reservation_packages
   get 'pages/functionroom'
   resources :package_line_items
  end
```

error stack:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Reservations):
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in 
`block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in 
`each'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in 
`constantize'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in 
`controller_reference'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:47:in 
`controller'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:26:in 
`call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in 
`call'
  sass (3.1.15) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) 
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) 
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in 
`call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in 
`call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) 
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in 
`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in 
`block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in 
`_run__321294476__call__156324443__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in 
`__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in 
`_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in 
`run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in 
`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in 
`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in 
`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) 
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) 
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in 
`call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) 
lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in 
`call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in 
`service'
  /home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in 
`run'
  /home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in 
`block in start_thread'


  Rendered 
/home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb 
within rescues/layout (1.2ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make route of it like in this way also

```
    resources :reservations do

     resources :pages do
        collection do
          get :functionroom
        end
     end
        resources :reservation_function_rooms
        resources :reservation_packages            
        resources :package_line_items
    end
```

but you can check routes through rake routes

it will sure work........

Answer (score 0):

run 'rake routes' to check your path

Comment: you use reservation_page_functionroom_path instead reservation_pages_functionroom_path

Comment: sorry for the misspelling im using `reservation_pages_functionroom_path(@reservation)` to route to my functionroom semi static page and still gives me the underutilized constant Reservation

Comment: what is name of the pages controller?

Comment: the controller is named pages_controller.rb
the action is called functionroom

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller name if it "reservations_controller.rb" or "reservation_controller"?

if it "reservation_controller.rb" then change it to "reservations_controller.rb"

### code

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: its reservations_controller.rb but i also dont know why it was rising that kind of error

Comment: See this source https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb . I would say keep it as you wish but the :resources may unable to find.